# T4 formatting generated properties

Tags: c#, t4

here is my T4 template method to generate property

```
public string Property(EdmProperty edmProperty)
{
    var fieldName = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"_{0}{1}",_code.Escape(edmProperty).Substring(0,1).ToLower(),_code.Escape(edmProperty).Substring(1));
    var propertyType = _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage);
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        @"{0} {1} {2} {6}{{{6}{3} get{{ return {4}; }}{6}{5} set{{ {4} = value; }}{6} }}",
        Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
        propertyType,
        _code.Escape(edmProperty),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
        fieldName,
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)),
        "");
}
```

it's generated code formated like that:

```
public string SomeProperty{ get{ return _someProperty; } set{ _someProperty = value; }}
```

I would like to format this to make it display like this:

```
public string SomeProperty
{
     get{ return _someProperty; }
     set{ _someProperty = value; }
}
```

I've tryed to make last parameter of `String.Format` in e.g(`{6}`):

1. `Environment.NewLine`
2. `"\r\n"`
3. `"\n"`

I'm also aware of auto-implemented properties, but need to do this this way.

**So what is the proper way to do this ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enviroment.NewLine` should be correct. It should look like this:

```
return string.Format(
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    @"{0} {1} {2} {6}{{{6}{3} get{{ return {4}; }}{6}{5} set{{ {4} = value; }}{6} }}",
    Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
    propertyType,
    _code.Escape(edmProperty),
    _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
    fieldName,
    _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)),
    Environment.NewLine);
```